# SQL Server Server Logins and Database Users

Tags: sql-server

At work we use AD groups to control access to SQL Server databases.

I can see these groups in `Security > Logins` and `(database) > Security > Users`.

The problem is that some DBs have 50+ such AD groups as valid logins/users and I know I am a member of more than one.

Is there a way I can determine which of these AD groups I am logged in under?

Answer (score 4):

You're effectively logged in as all of them. You'll have the union of all of the individual permissions granted to each group that you're a member of.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 straight forward built in commands that can help with what you are looking for:

First the extended procedure XP_LoginInfo (available at least since SS2000) will show you all the connection paths a particular login is allowed to use to connect to the instance with

```
DECLARE @LoginName sysname
SELECT @LoginName = SYSTEM_USER

EXEC xp_LoginInfo @AcctName = @LoginName, @Option = 'all'
```

All the group names shown under the last column "permission path" are the groups that the supplied LoginName is part of. Also note the "privilege" column; it will show if a login has **admin** or **user** level rights on the instance.

Now, the function fn_my_permissions (available since SS2005) will show you all the permissions the *currently connected login* has on the **current database** or the **server**.

```
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'DATABASE');

SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER');
```

As Damien_The_Unbeliever responded on 11/28/12, basically the final list of permissions is the union of all the permissions assigned--both Grant and Deny--to each group's (and individually where an ID has been added explicitly) *permission path* you see by executing xp_LoginInfo.

So the answer basically is that you don't exactly connect with any one group when there are multiple allowed paths. Instead, in essence, you connect with them all. While nowhere does SQL Server clearly show or even state the 'unioned' nature of permissions, it can be inferred with the above 2 commands.

A ton of useful Security Catalog Views can be found on MSDN [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178542%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)